# Plotly, Changing the hover text

Tags: hover, plotly

I am trying to change the hover text in plotly.
As an example there is

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
    hovertemplate =
    '<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}'+
    '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>'+
    '<b>%{text}</b>',
    text = ['Custom text {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(5)],
    showlegend = False))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [3.02825,2.63728,4.83839,3.8485,1.73463],
    hovertemplate = 'Price: %{y:$.2f}<extra></extra>',
    showlegend = False))

fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel_align = 'right',
    title = "Set hover text with hovertemplate")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Can you see the part in blue where it says "trace 0". Where does that come from?
If you hover in the red curve you will notice that something similar does not appear.

I want to reproduce this, so I want to understand where that is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable/disable the `trace0, trace1,...` text for each set of points by removing/adding the `<extra></extra>` tag. The documentation for hover text customization can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/).

To make `trace1` appear on your second set of points, remove the `<extra></extra>` tag.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
    hovertemplate =
    '<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}'+
    '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>'+
    '<b>%{text}</b>',
    text = ['Custom text {}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(5)],
    showlegend = False))

## Remove the extra tag
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = [1,2,3,4,5],
    y = [3.02825,2.63728,4.83839,3.8485,1.73463],
    hovertemplate = 'Price: %{y:$.2f}',
    showlegend = False))

fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel_align = 'right',
    title = "Set hover text with hovertemplate")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I don't want to unable it, but to the contrary, make it appear everywhere. (like in the red curve). By default it appears but when I modify the hover text it dissapears.  I will run some experiments with your info to see how it goes!

Comment: Updated— I hope this helps